# how to show the size of zip at the client side while zippping large batch of files on web server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, json

When the user selects the list of files from a page and hit's download selected, then a post back happens to server and starts zipping on the server. This works great until we hit the timeout on the page ( which is default to 90 seconds ) and just returns the process to the page even though the backend process is still zipping. Is it possible to show the size of zip file when the file is being zipped instead of waiting till the end to provide the download link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveX components to do that:

```
var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var d = filepath;
var e = oas.getFile(d);
var f = e.size;
alert(f + " bytes");
}
```

but it will limit you to IE and should have appropriate IE security settings.

Comment: How about firefox and chrome?